# Unix command to exclude a particular directory and its contents using chown, while permission to other directories are applied

Tags: linux, shell, unix, chown

I'm using the below command to change the ownership (using chown) of sets directories and files present under a `/opt/var` and trying to exclude `.snapshot` directory and its contents.

`find /opt/var/ ! -name '.snapshot' | xargs -I {} chown 2000:2000 {};`

However, it only excludes .snapshot but its contents get permission applied.

Am I missing anything here? I am trying to achieve in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `chmod`  is for changing the permissions while `chown` is for changing the owners. Anyways, to exclude a directory, use `-path` option:

```sh
find /opt/var/ ! -path '/opt/var/.snapshot*' | xargs -I {} chown 2000:2000 {}
```

Or

```sh
find /opt/var/ ! -path '*.snapshot*' | xargs -I {} chown 2000:2000 {}
```

Comment: my bad, I meant to use chown only. Your answer helps. Appreciated it! accepted!  - Thank you.